# how to copy from a property file to xml

Tags: shell-script, xml

I have a xml file which contains some `path` at multiple places.

Now I want to fetch value from a `.properties` file mentioned and replace part of `path` where ever it is present in xml.

Let's consider I have an xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
...
...
<classpath>

      <pathelement location="/profiles/sh/finalFolder/Apache/example.jar" />

</classpath>

<property name="executable" value="/profiles/sh/finalFolder/Apache/instjamr/install" />

<fileset dir="/profiles/sh/finalFolder/Apache/ant"/>
```

this xml file conatins path `/profiles/sh/finalFolder` with some suffix at  many places.

Now, I have a `path.properties` file which contains (key,value) pairs such as

`FinalFolder=/new/final/exit` (user can edit value anytime in property file)

I want to replace the `path` with the value mentioned in `.properties` file for the key **FinalFolder**.

I need to write code in `.sh` file to do the job.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Expected o/p is oldpath i.e,  /profiles/sh/finalFolder to be replaced by /new/final/exit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First extract the path from the `path.properties`file:

```
newPath=`sed -n 's/FinalFolder=//p' path.properties`
```

Then replace the old path with the new (using `-` as separator instead of `/` to make it more readable:

```
sed -i "s-/profiles/sh/finalFolder-$newPath-g" file.xml
```

In the script I suggest some error handling incase there is no FinalFolder item in the file or it is malformed.